# Asymmetric vs Nonsymmetric Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, symmetry

What are the differences between an *asymmetric* graph and a *nonsymmetric* graph?

I think it is:
**Asymmetric**: No two distinct vertices are symmetric
**Nonsymmetric**: No complete asymmetry or symmetry for every vertex
**Symmetric**: Every two distinct vertices are symmetric

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are multiple uses of the term *symmetric* which can cause this sort of confusion. Here are few uses. A symmetric graph could refer to

1. a graph that is both edge- and vertex-transitive;
2. a graph that is arc-transitive;
3. a graph that is undirected. This is your suggestion!

As for the other terms, fortunately they tend to have slightly less ambiguous meaning.

- An *asymmetric* graph is a graph $G$ such that Aut$(G)=0$, the trivial group. Since automorphisms can be thought of as the symmetry of a group, this term makes some sense.
- An *antisymmetric* graph is a directed graph where distinct vertices are connected by edges going only in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a clear difference between asymmetric and nonsymmetric. It's probably down to the author, but I'm still to see the same author using both words simultaneously, and thereby meaning two different things. So my guess is that "nonsymmetric" is simply a barbarism for "asymmetric" (which is the correct Greek opposite of "symmetric"), just like people say nonhomogeneous (or non-homoegeneous) when they mean "heterogeneous".